# dropwizard 0.7 @Session annotation

Tags: java, session, dropwizard

i'm trying to get Dropwizard working with sessions.
I've read that in 0.7, Dropwizard added session support.
from release notes:
"Added support for HTTP Sessions. Add the annotated parameter to your resource method: @Session HttpSession session to have the session context injected."

i have a sample resource class, that gets a user/password from an http get request, and i want to save the user name in the session:

```
@GET
public Response auth(@QueryParam("user") String user, @QueryParam("password") String password,         @Session HttpSession session) throws URISyntaxException {
    URI rootUri = getApplicationRootUri();
    if(!user.equals(config.getUser()) || !password.equals(config.getPassword())) {

        return Response.temporaryRedirect(rootUri).build();
    }
    session.setAttribute("user", user);
    return Response.temporaryRedirect( new URI("/../index.html")).build();
}
```

when trying to log in from my app I'm getting:

```
ERROR [2014-05-17 10:33:45,244] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest: A message body reader for Java class javax.servlet.http.HttpSession, and Java type interface javax.servlet.http.HttpSession, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.
```

I've tried looking on some tests from the dropwizard source on github and it seems that the @Session annotation is used the same way as in my code.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Taking cue from exception message "MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found " : Could the exception be due to response type not being specified and handled properly? And not because of session.

Comment: im new to http, but i've also tried to copy the session test from the dropwizard src (https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/master/dropwizard-jersey/src/test/java/io/dropwizard/jersey/sessions), and send an http post with plain text as the content type (curl -X GET -H "Content-Type:text/plain"  http://localhost:8080/session -d "pipp"), and got the same error. . when removing the HttpSession param, all works fine.

Comment: it seems like the HttpSessionProvider is not registered when starting the jetty server, is there any other configuration required to enable sessions? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I had to do (dropwizard 0.7) in the application class was:

```
    environment.jersey().register(HttpSessionProvider.class);
    environment.servlets().setSessionHandler(new SessionHandler());
```